# ms-access could not delete

Tags: mysql, ms-access

ms-access is connecting to a local mysql database

the following code returns an error:

```
Public Function run_sql(strSql As String)
On Error GoTo lblError
CurrentDb.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
lblExit:
    Exit Function
lblError:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Resume lblExit
End Function
```

strSql = "DELETE FROM tblUsersSubjects WHERE user_id=2007;" - i ran this statement it works perfectly, but access is giving me this error: 3086: Could not delete from specified tables

what is the cause of this error?

table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbluserssubjects` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `other` varchar(50) default NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

please note that i AM able perform the needed delete operation my using the shell, instead of access

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Jet/ACE SQL DELETE statements require something between DELETE and FROM, as in "DELETE * FROM tblUsersSubjects WHERE user_id=2007" or "DELETE * FROM user_id WHERE user_id=2007". While other SQL dialects don't require an object of the DELETE predicate, Jet/ACE SQL seems to do so. Try putting the * in there and see if your CurrentDb.Execute now works.

Comment: If you want to "preview" (in datasheet view) what you're about to delete, Access requires something between DELETE and FROM.  But to execute a DELETE statement, you don't.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "Jet/ACE SQL DELETE statements require something between DELETE and FROM" -- certainly not true for ANSI-92 Query Mode. Anyhow, the unit of work in a DELETE statement is the row, therefore requiring an asterisk, column list, literal, etc makes no sense. What would one expect DELETE customer_name FROM Customers to do? Drop the column?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within Access can you open your linked table, tblUsersSubjects, in datasheet view and edit or delete in datasheet view?  If not, Access may be treating the connection to your MySql table as read-only.  Try deleting the link (in Access; not the actual table in MySql).  Then re-link the table in Access and make sure to tell Access which field (or combination of fields) to use as a primary key.  If Access isn't aware of a linked table's primary key, the link will be read-only.

After off-line discussions with Alex, I want to add to this answer:

Access originally didn't recognize what to
use as a primary key, so your linked table was read-only from the Access side.  I'll guess that was because your CREATE TABLE statement didn't
include a primary key constraint.  But I don't actually know the
details of how Access *automagically* identifies the primary key when linking to an
external table.  Perhaps, in the absence of an explicitly defined
primary key, it might look for a field with Not Null and Unique
constraints.  But the CREATE TABLE statement didn't include any unique constraints on your MySql
table either.

So when Access is not able to automagically guess the external table's primary key, you must tell it which field (or fields) to use as the primary key ... **unless** you want the linked table to be read-only from Access.

Comment: Paste your SQL statement, "DELETE FROM tblUsersSubjects WHERE user_id=2007;", into the SQL View for a new query in Access.  Does it work there?

Comment: All I can suggest now is to check MySql logs to see why your DELETE is rejected in one situation but not the others.

Comment: After pasting it into the SQL view in Acces, go to DESIGN view and then back to SQL view and my bet is that Access has reformatted the SQL in a manner that will work if you use the same formatting with your EXECUTE statement.

Comment: My understanding of how Jet/ACE recognizes PKs in external data sources is that it queries the ODBC driver for metadata about the table when you create the linked table.

Comment: Based on off-site communications, my understanding is the OP resolved this one by dropping the link, then specifying the Pkey field when he re-linked the table.

Answer (score 1):

Is the table in Access or MySql? If it's in MySql it's likely that you don't have the proper permissions to edit table data. Check your connection string that points to the MySql table and make sure that whoever you're connecting as has delete permissions on that table.

Also - does this table have any foreign key relationships to other tables? Perhaps you are trying to delete a record that would cause a violation to some other table's primary key.

Comment: it has full permissions, im able to do it on different tables

Comment: can you post the table structure of tblUsersSubjects?

Comment: posted........please note that i AM able perform the needed delete operation my using the shell, instead of access

Comment: Just going out on a limb here - is it possible you have a local Access table that is linked to tblUsersSubjects and you are violating a referential integrity rule?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a case-sensitive issue?

You typed: "tbluserssubjects" for the table structure, but in the query you typed "tblUsersSubjects" (capital U and S)