# how do i set UniqueRecords property of the query to Yes?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

i have this problem:

[ms-access could not delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355234/ms-access-could-not-delete)

and i found a potential solution here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240098

however it asks me to follow these steps:

1. Open the delete query in Design view.
2. On the View menu, click Properties.
3. Set the UniqueRecords property to Yes.
4. Save the query, and then close it.

how do i follow these directions? how can i open a delete query?

Comment: That knowledge base article refers to a delete query with multiple tables.  Your problem delete query, in your other question, attempts to delete from a single table.  So, I don't think the knowledge base article applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For step 1 find the query in the Access database container.  Right click on it and choose Design View.

For step 2, once you've clicked on View >> Prpoerties you may need to click on the top half of the query design view to view the query properties rather than the field properties.

For step 4 click on the floppy diskette image on the toolbar.  (Hmm, what would be a good icon these days for saving rather than a floppy diskette?)

Comment: I long ago started calling it the "television" because a client I was training responded to my explanation with "Floppy disk? You mean the *television*?" So now all my clients are accustomed to hearing "click the televison" as the instruction for saving something.